# OS X Disable Internal Network Between Apps Temporairly

Tags: eclipse, macos, rest, networking

I am supporting development of a client application that will be communicating to a seperate enterprise service bus.  We have our own black box services to develop against.  We each host multiple REST endpoints (using RESTeasy) to communicate.

One scenario we need to demonstrate to our client is sudden loss of network connectivity between my client application and their ESB with later network restoration.  In the client demonstration, they plan to have separate workstations connected by a router and pull the cables for a few minutes and then reconnect them.

My question is that, while keeping both app running in eclipse on my workstation, can I temporarily block them from making successful REST requests to each other and then restore the connection?  As best as possible to simulate the demonstration objective of pulling the network cables.

OS X El Capitan; Eclipse Neon; Jetty 9.2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self Answer:
Not as elegant as I would like, but works because the endpoints are already compile-time configurable.

1. Add an entry to /etc/hosts for a volatile domain pointing to 127.0.0.1

127.0.0.1        volatileDomain

2. Configure my endpoints to point to volatileDomain.
3. Start both apps.
4. Edit and save /etc/hosts to comment out the volatileDomain line.
5. Watch disconnection logic handle the current state.
6. Edit and save /etc/hosts to reintroduce the volatileDomain line.
7. Watch reconnection logic reestablish the connected state.